# Flutter Firebase storage upload implementation

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

Can anyone explain with an example the implementation for uploading an image to Firebase storage?
I'm sure that my problem is exactly with this method:

```
Future<TaskSnapshot> uploadImage(String user, File file) async =>
      await _db.ref(user).child('images/${file.path}').putFile(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code makes it seem like you're trying to upload a file to the Firebase Realtime Database:

```
await _db.ref(user).child('images/${file.path}').putFile(file);
```

You can't upload files to the Firebase Realtime Database, only to Firebase Storage. For more on this see the documentation on [uploading files from Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files).